# Realizar inserção em uma tabela com chave estrangeira

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, orientação-a-objetos

```
include_once 'acesso_bd/conexao_bd.php';

class PropriedadeDAO { 


    function inserirPropriedadeBD($propriedade) { 

        $nome = $propriedade->getNome();
        $endereco = $propriedade->getEndereco();
        $telefone = $propriedade->getTelefone();

        $conexaobd = new ConexaoBD;

        $conexao = $conexaobd->conectarAoBD();

        $sql = "INSERT INTO propriedade (nome, endereco, telefone) VALUES ('$nome', '$endereco', '$telefone')";

        if (!mysqli_query($conexao, $sql)) {
            echo "Erro: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conexao);
        }


    }
```

o código acima refere-se ao cadastro de uma propriedade, onde o seu ID é `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

```
include_once 'acesso_bd/conexao_bd.php';

class TalhaoDAO { 


    function inserirTalhaoBD($talhao) { 

        $nome = $talhao->getNome();


        $conexaobd = new ConexaoBD;

        $conexao = $conexaobd->conectarAoBD();


        $sql = "INSERT INTO talhao (nome, id_propriedade) VALUES ('$nome', LAST_INSERT_ID())";

        if (!mysqli_query($conexao, $sql)) {
            echo "Erro: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conexao);
        }


    }
```

Esse é o código de cadastro do Talhao, que necessariamente precisa da chave estrangeira `"id_propriedade"` para ser identificado. Utilizei o `LAST_INSERT_ID`, o problema é que está me retornando o seguinte erro ao tentar cadastrar o Talhao:

> Erro: INSERT INTO talhao (nome, id_propriedade) VALUES ('aaa', LAST_INSERT_ID())
>       Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`teste`.`talhao`, CONSTRAINT `id_propriedade_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`id_propriedade`) REFERENCES `propriedade` (`id_propriedade`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `propriedade` (
  `id_propriedade` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `endereco` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `telefone` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_propriedade`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `talhao` (
  `id_parcela` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `id_propriedade` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_parcela`),
  KEY `id_propriedade` (`id_propriedade`),
  KEY `id_propriedade_fk` (`id_propriedade`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB ;
```

Comment: Opa, aqui na [documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) pode ser que lhe ajuda. Se não me engano no Mysql você tem que colocar '`' antes e depois das colunas que você deseja inserir valores.

Comment: Oi, Marconi. Obrigada pelo comentário, mas não acredito que as aspas  seja o problema. Fiz o teste aqui e não deu certo.

Comment: Sabrina, pode [edit] a pergunta e adicionar a estrutura das tabelas?

Comment: Estruturas adicionadas.

Comment: Qual a estrutura das tabelas? Tenta alterar nome da primary key da tabela propriedade e deixar diferente do nome da foreign key da tabela talhao. Mas posta a estrutura das tabelas por favor.

Comment: Agora que vi a estrutura...tenta fazer o que eu falei e coloca por exemplo,  a primary key de propriedade como `id_prop` e a de talhao que é fk, deixa como está. Nomes iguais para PK e FK geralmente dão dor de cabeça.

Comment: Diéfani, eu já havia conseguido realizar inserções manuais diretamente no banco, indicando o código exato da propriedade na FK e deu certo. Por isso que eu acredito que o problema realmente esteja no LAST_INSERT_ID(). Porém, vou fazer um teste com a sua sugestão.

Comment: Diéfani, fiz um teste com a sua sugestão e continua dando o mesmo erro.

Comment: Sabrina, na tabela talhao a definição de FK seria `CONSTRAINT id_propriedade_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_propriedade) REFERENCES propriedade(id_propriedade)`, pois KEY é sinonimo de  INDEX

Answer (score 1):

Classe PropriedadeDAO

```
include_once 'acesso_bd/conexao_bd.php';

class PropriedadeDAO { 


    function inserirPropriedadeBD($propriedade) { 

        $nome = $propriedade->getNome();
        $endereco = $propriedade->getEndereco();
        $telefone = $propriedade->getTelefone();

        $conexaobd = new ConexaoBD;

        $conexao = $conexaobd->conectarAoBD();

        $sql = "INSERT INTO propriedade (nome, endereco, telefone) VALUES ('$nome', '$endereco', '$telefone')";

        if (!mysqli_query($conexao, $sql)) {
            echo "Erro: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conexao);
        }else {
        $propriedade->setID(mysqli_insert_id($conexao)); // Alteração
        }


    }
```

Classe Propriedade

```
<?php

include_once '../dao/dao_propriedade.php';

class Propriedade { 
    private $id;
    private $nome; 
    private $endereco; 
    private $telefone; 

    function setID($id) { 
        $this->id = $id;
    } 

    function setNome($nome) { 
        $this->nome = $nome;
    } 

    function setEndereco($endereco) { 
        $this->endereco = $endereco;
    } 

    function setTelefone($telefone) { 
        $this->telefone = $telefone;
    } 

    function getID() { 
        return $this->id; 
    } 

    function getNome() { 
        return $this->nome; 
    } 

    function getEndereco() { 
        return $this->endereco;  
    } 

    function getTelefone() { 
        return $this->telefone;
    }
```

Classe TalhaoDAO `

```
include_once 'acesso_bd/conexao_bd.php';
include_once '../modelo/modelo_propriedade.php';

class TalhaoDAO { 



    function inserirTalhaoBD($talhao) { 

        $nome = $talhao->getNome();
        $idPropriedade = $talhao->getPropriedade(); //Alteração


        $conexaobd = new ConexaoBD;

        $conexao = $conexaobd->conectarAoBD();


        $sql = "INSERT INTO talhao (`nome`, `id_propriedade`) VALUES ('$nome', '$idPropriedade')";

        if (!mysqli_query($conexao, $sql)) {
            echo "Erro: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conexao);
        }


    } `
```

Classe Talhao `

```
include_once '../dao/dao_talhao.php';

class Talhao { 
    private $id;
    private $nome; 
    private $endereco; 
    private $telefone; 
    private $id_propriedade;

    function setID($id) { 
        $this->id = $id;
    } 

    function setNome($nome) { 
        $this->nome = $nome;
    } 

    function setPropriedade($id_propriedade){
    $this->id_propriedade = $id_propriedade;
    }


    function getID() { 
        return $this->id; 
    } 

    function getNome() { 
        return $this->nome; 
    } 

    function getPropriedade(){
     return $this->id_propriedade;
    }`
```

O erro que está retornando:

> Erro: INSERT INTO talhao (`nome`, `id_propriedade`) VALUES ('B2', '')
>   Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`teste`.`talhao`, CONSTRAINT `id_propriedade_fk` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`id_propriedade`) REFERENCES `propriedade` (`id_prop`) ON DELETE NO
>   ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

Answer (score 1):

Você adicionou `KEY` em vez de `FOREIGN KEY`, ou seja, sua tabela tem indice mas não tem chave estrangeira. Dessa forma com certeza vai dar erro de `CONSTRAINT` e `FK`. Faz um backup primeiro e depois dá um `DROP TABLE talhao`. É melhor deletar a tabela para não correr risco de alguma coisa ficar pra trás ao dar um `ALTER TABLE` e cria a tabela como coloquei abaixo e vê se funciona. Eu retirei as aspas apenas por questão de preferencia.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS talhao (
  id_parcela int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nome varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  id_propriedade int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_parcela),
CONSTRAINT id_propriedade_fk FOREIGN KEY (id_propriedade) REFERENCES propriedade(id_propriedade)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Abaixo está meu export que eu criei de teste, também usando phpMyAdmin.

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.5.2
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Jun 22, 2017 at 11:47 PM
-- Server version: 10.1.16-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 5.5.38

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `teste`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `propriedade`
--

CREATE TABLE `propriedade` (
  `id_propriedade` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `endereco` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `telefone` varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `talhao`
--

CREATE TABLE `talhao` (
  `id_parcela` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `id_propriedade` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `propriedade`
--
ALTER TABLE `propriedade`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_propriedade`);

--
-- Indexes for table `talhao`
--
ALTER TABLE `talhao`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_parcela`),
  ADD KEY `id_propriedade_fk` (`id_propriedade`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `propriedade`
--
ALTER TABLE `propriedade`
  MODIFY `id_propriedade` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `talhao`
--
ALTER TABLE `talhao`
  MODIFY `id_parcela` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `talhao`
--
ALTER TABLE `talhao`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `id_propriedade_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`id_propriedade`) REFERENCES `propriedade` (`id_propriedade`);

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: Fiz como você sugeriu e apareceu o erro 1215.

Comment: Error: 1215 SQLSTATE: HY000 (ER_CANNOT_ADD_FOREIGN)

Message: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: Você deletou a tabela talhao e copiou e colou o que eu coloquei aqui ou você digitou? Você criou por meio de código ou pelas ferramentas do gerenciador que você está usando? Porque eu criei aqui e deu certo. O que você está usando para gerenciar o BD? PHPMyAdmin, MySQL Workbench...?

Comment: Eu deletei a tabela talhão e copiei e colei o que você digitou. Eu to usando o PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: É local o teste? Xampp ou Wamp? Geralmente tenho problemas de BD quando testo localmente e o problema é resolvido reiniciando os servidores. Acima eu fiz uma edição e coloquei o export o banco de dados. Aqui não deu problema.

Comment: Sem a chave estrangeira, se funcionar, é possível que o banco insira valores vazios, NULL ou 0.

Comment: É o Wamp. Eu vou tentar de novo. Mas agora eu já consegui inserir e remover a mensagem de erro que tava dando inicialmente, o problema é que ao invés de inserir o último ID na chave estrangeira, tá inserindo 0.

Comment: Ah, entendi. Então eu vou tentar inserir novamente do jeito que você digitou.

Comment: Consegui adicionar a estrutura da tabela da maneira que você sugeriu, mas agora voltei ao erro inicial hahaha.

Comment: Erro: INSERT INTO talhao (`nome`, `id_propriedade`) VALUES ('L6', '')
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`teste`.`talhao`, CONSTRAINT `id_propriedade_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`id_propriedade`) REFERENCES `propriedade` (`id_prop`))

Comment: Se as suas tabelas estiverem identicas as minhas, pode trocar no seu código o `id_prop` por `id_propriedade`. Por que o erro agora tem dois parenteses fechando no final?

Comment: É que você havia sugerido a mudança do nome do id da propriedade, aí eu tinha feito assim. Mas já coloquei como id_propriedade novamente e segue o erro. To quase desistindo rs

Comment: Pior que eu testo aqui com o banco como te mandei e com o código que um rapaz colocou abaixo e dá certinho.

Comment: Pois é, ele também disse a mesma coisa. Provavelmente eu to fazendo alguma coisa errada então.

Comment: Definindo o número do id da chave estrangeira eu consegui inserir. Isso significa que provavelmente o erro está na recuperação do id da propriedade :/

Answer (score 1):

O formulário de inserção da propriedade:

```
<body>
<h1> Nova propriedade</h1>
<form action="../controle/controle_propriedade.php" method="post">
    Nome:
    <br/>
    <input name="nome" type="text" value="" required="required">
    <br/>
    Endereco:
    <br/>
    <input name="endereco" type="text" value="" required="required">
    <br/>
    Telefone:
    <br/>
    <input name="telefone" type="text" value="" required="required">
    <br/>
    <input name="acao" type="hidden" value="inserir">
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar">
</form>
<br/>
```

O código de controle da propriedade:

```
include_once '../modelo/modelo_propriedade.php';

$acao = ($_POST["acao"]);

switch ($acao) {
    case "inserir":
        $propriedade = new Propriedade;
        $propriedade->setNome($_POST["nome"]);
        $propriedade->setEndereco($_POST["endereco"]);
        $propriedade->setTelefone($_POST["telefone"]);

        $propriedade->cadastrarPropriedade();

        include_once '../visao/novo_talhao.html';

        break;
```